# LDBL_MAX and LDBL_MIN returns an a wrong answer when I submmited my code to an online judge

Tags: c++, floating-point

I'm practicing some questions online using an online judge that does not support English; query: should I link the question (that's not in English) here?

The problem is quite simple, I'm asked to input `N` which will be the amount of numbers that I will insert. Then, I'm asked to find out which has the biggest value and smallest value. I'm also asked to calculate the average and the standard deviation of those numbers. I'm provided a formula for the standard deviation, too. Problem is, when I tried using `LDBL_MIN` and `LDBL_MAX` in my code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    long double maxValue = LDBL_MIN, minValue = LDBL_MAX, sds = 0, avg = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        long double temp;
        cin >> temp;
        if (maxValue < temp)
            maxValue = temp;
        if (minValue > temp)
            minValue = temp;

        avg += temp;
        sds += temp * temp;
    }

    avg /= N;
    sds = sqrt((sds - (N * avg * avg)) / (N - 1));
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << minValue << " " << maxValue << " " << avg << " " << sds << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I get a wrong answer (I got one wrong answer out of four test cases). So one of my friends suggested me to try using the lower bound - 1 and upper bound - 1 of the constraint given by the question and it returned all correct. I changed the `maxValue` part to:

`long double maxValue = -1000001, minValue = 1000001`

What happened here? I thought that `LDBL_MIN` and `LDBL_MAX` would both give the same results as the alternative my friend suggested.

Comment: Which compiler did you use ? when LBDL_MIN/MAX did not work as expected, you should use maxValue = minValue = first_input_value.

Comment: Was you code required to handle subnormal, zero, and negative inputs?

Comment: You are probably focusing on the wrong problem.  `avg /= N` is not going to end well when the machine test your program with N==0.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Replacing LBDL_MIN with -1000001 should change behavior for inputs in the range (-1000001, LBDL_MIN), which includes the negative numbers greater than -1000001, zero, and the subnormal positive numbers.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: Ah, `LDBL_MIN` is actually misnamed; it should be `LDBL_MIN_POSITIVE_NORMAL`. That could explain OP’s observation.

Comment: @Patricia Yes, the test case included negative numbers for the data, but the `N` has a constraint of 1 until 100. It also has the value zero for some data. I'm not quite sure what subnormal means.

Comment: @Hans Ah sorry, I should've included the info about the constraint for `N`. It will always be larger than 0 and smaller than 101.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LDBL_MIN` is the smallest **positive** normalized value that can be represented as a `long double`. So it's slightly greater than 0. That's different from the integer macros, which give the smallest value that can be represented. Floating-point types are usually symmetrical, so use `-LDBL_MAX` to get the smallest representable value. Or, in C++, use `std::numeric_limits<long double>::lowest()`.

Comment: I see! That's why I got it wrong. I'm supposed to test the negative inputs, too. I thought that LDBL_MIN would give me the true smallest value of `long double`< hence the counterpart of LDBL_MAX. Thank you, I did not know that I could do `-LDBL_MIN` to achieve the same effect.

Comment: One thing, though, what does normalized value mean?

Comment: Re: normalized value: suppose you have a personal rule to always write decimal values with one digit to the left of the decimal point: 1.03e6, etc. And suppose you have a rule that the exponent can't be any smaller than -10. So 1.00e-10 is the smallest **normalized** value you can represent. In order to have values that are closer to 0, you can go with 0.10e-10, and 0.01e-10. Those are **denormalized** values -- they have the minimum allowed exponent and don't have a 1 to the left of the decimal point. You get smaller values, but with less precision. That's what many floating-point systems do.

Comment: I see. I meant `-LDBL_MAX`, by the way. In regard to normalized value, why do I have to follow that rule (always writing decimal values with one digit to the left of the decimal point)? What benefit does following that rule give? Also, wouldn't it be equal to 0 if I wrote 0.00e-10 instead of 0.01e-10?

Comment: The point of that analogy is that that’s how floating-point math works on many systems.